# Lotus Notes - .Net sidebar application

Tags: .net, wpf, interop, lotus-notes, sidebar

Is it possible to integrate a .NET (WPF) application as a sidebar application in Lotus Notes?

Comment: I feel sad for a person who asks how to interop with that monster. ;) Have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely is possible. In Lotus Notes 8 we introduced the Eclipse RCP to the client, you can use SWT views to re-parent the .NET application. Similar to how we show the older NSF based applications in the eclipse client.